# Join Questiion - How to return vacancies where no candidates have applied - i.e. 0 results

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following SQL statement works fine for when someone has actually applied for a given position at a school, but does not display details of positions where there have been no applications. How do I incorporate this?

```
select school.school_id, school_name,position,
positions_vacant.vacancy_id, DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d')   
start_date, positions_vacant.status,count(candidate.candidate_id) 
candidate_count
 from positions_vacant 
 join school on (positions_vacant.school_id = school.school_id)
  join application on (positions_vacant.vacancy_id = 
  application.vacancy_id)
  join candidate on (application.candidate_id = candidate.candidate_id)
  group by school_name,position, DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),       
  positions_vacant.status
  order by school_name, start_date;
```

I attached an image to display the returned dataset.

[image: dataset]

Help would be appreciated, I'm really weak at this stuff.

Comment: Use left join. Your join is an implicit inner join. So just put the word left in front of all of your joins and then, take some time and read up on joins. It's the most fundamental aspect of RDMS queries

Comment: Please remove the sql-server tag and add the tags appropriate for the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT s.school_id,
  school_name,
  position,
  p.vacancy_id,
  DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d') start_date,
  p.status,
  COUNT(c.candidate_id) candidate_count
FROM positions_vacant p
LEFT JOIN school s
ON (p.school_id = s.school_id)
LEFT JOIN application a
ON (p.vacancy_id = a.vacancy_id)
LEFT JOIN candidate c
ON (a.candidate_id = c.candidate_id)
GROUP BY school_name,
  position,
  DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),
  p.status
ORDER BY school_name,
  start_date;
```